# Rest API App working in 'Sandbox' but not 'Live'

Tags: python, django, rest, paypal, live

For some reason *My App* is not working on **live** mode using PayPal REST API. This is the error I get on my Apache server:

[:error] [pid 29701] WARNING:root:Not logging full request/response headers and body in live mode for compliance

Here is my code, I'm using Django:

```
def payPaypal(sku, price, ship_code):
        has_paypal_error = False
        paypal_approval_url = None
        paypalrestsdk.configure({
                'mode': settings.PAYPAL_STATUS, # live
                'client_id': settings.PAYPAL_LIVE_CLIENT_ID, 
                'client_secret': settings.PAYPAL_LIVE_CLIENT_SECRET 
        })

        payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
                "intent": "sale",
                "payer": {
                        "payment_method": "paypal" },
                "redirect_urls": {
                        "return_url": "mysite_url/thanks",
                        "cancel_url": "mysite_url" },

                "transactions": [ {
                        "amount": {
                                "total": price[ship_code].amount,
                                "currency": price[ship_code].currency },
                        "description": "my description.",
                        "item_list": {
                                "items": [ {
                                        "name": "name description",
                                        "sku": sku,
                                        "quantity": "1",
                                        "price": price[ship_code].amount,
                                        "currency": price[ship_code].currency
                                }]
                        }
                }]
        })
        if payment.create():
                for link in payment.links:
                        if link.rel == "approval_url":
                                paypal_approval_url = link.href 
        else:
                has_paypal_error = True

        return has_paypal_error, paypal_approval_url
```

And inside my form:

```
    elif cd['payment_type'] == "2": # PayPal
                        is_paypal = True
                        has_paypal_error, paypal_approval_url = payPaypal(sku, price, ship_code)
                        payment_error_msg = _('Something went wrong, please try again')
```

thanks.html

```
if request.method == 'GET' and request.GET.get('paymentId'):
        paymentId = request.GET.get('paymentId')
        payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find(paymentId)
        payer_id = payment.payer.payer_info.payer_id

        if payment.execute({"payer_id": payer_id}):
                sendInvoiceEmailToUser(email_to_send_invoce, email_invoce_lang)
                sendSuccessNotificationToCrew(email_crew)
                return render(request, 'thanks.html')
```

Looking at the response going "live", it looks like the "approval_url" is correct:

```
[{'href': u'https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-######', 'method': u'GET', 'rel': u'self'}, 
{'href': u'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-####', 'method': u'REDIRECT', 'rel': u'approval_url'}, 
{'href': u'https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-####/execute', 'method': u'POST', 'rel': u'execute'}]
```

Live APP Settings

[image: my live settings in REST API]

Comment: That Warn dosen't indicate that the payment isn't processing - What is expected behavior and how do you know it's not occurring?

Comment: When the user press 'checkout' the page redirects to 500.html Site. But this just happen in 'live' mode, for 'sandbox' everything works fine.

Comment: If you're getting a redirect to a 500 on your server, the problem rests in how you're handling the request.  Confirm that the redirect URL is accurate.  You might try just having thanks.html dump the request it recieved - to gather more information.

Comment: Thank you! @DanO'Boyle I'll see if I found the problem! I'll let you know Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, and it had nothing to do with PayPal.

I forgot to add the paypal domains in the ALLOWED_HOSTS in my settings.py from my Django App

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ 'mysite.com.', '.paypal.com', 'paypal.com.' ]
```

Comment: I don't think this solved your problem.  ALLOWED_HOSTS only refers to domains that your site can serve.  You wouldn't be serving from paypal.com, only recieving a request from paypal.  Did you maybe adjust your CSRF token settings for that view?